# In a Linux shell how can I process each line of a multiline string?

Tags: linux, shell, foreach

While in a Linux shell I have a string which has the following contents:

```
cat
dog
bird
```

I want to pass each item as an argument to another function. How can I do this?

Comment: Whoever threw the offtopic close vote against this needs to reevaluate their contribution...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use this (it is loop of reading each line from file `file`)

```
cat file | while read -r a; do echo $a; done
```

where the `echo $a` is whatever you want to do with current line.

UPDATE: from commentators (thanks!)

If you have no file with multiple lines, but have a variable with multiple lines, use

```
echo "$variable" | while read -r a; do echo $a; done
```

UPDATE2: "`read -r`" is recommended to disable backslashed (`\`) chars interpretation (check mtraceur comments; supported in most shells). It is documented in POSIX 1003.1-2008 http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html

> By default, unless the -r option is specified, `<backslash>` shall act as an escape character. .. The following option is supported: `-r` - Do not treat a `<backslash>` character in any special way. Consider each  to be part of the input line.

Comment: `while read -r ... done < file` No need for `cat`, but the OP said "I have a string" which means it's in a variable rather than a file, so `echo $var | while ...`

Comment: @Dennis: Rather `while ... done <<< "$var"` (at least in Bash)

Comment: @Philipp: That's true, but the question is tagged `[shell]` so I posted the portable version.

Comment: I'd say `read -r` should always be used instead of just `read` unless you explicitly want to have read interpret certain escape sequences like it does without the `-r` option. Even in examples where it doesn't make a difference, because it's so easy for people to not find out about that historical oddity in `read`'s behavior until it breaks their script in an obscure way on very specific inputs.

Comment: I guess as a follow-up, since the question is tagged `[shell]` and the `-r` option for `read` isn't portable to a small selection of shells in use to this day (looking mostly at you Solaris, way to ruin it for everybody), it's reasonable to make a comment about how `read -r` is POSIX and generally portable, but not "portability-zealot portable", or whatever the right wording would be.

Comment: @mtraceur, SunOS still shipped a pre-POSIX shell in the mid-2000s, but isn't that more than a decade ago now? I'd been under the impression that they shipped a proper POSIX sh pretty much concurrent with the rename to Solaris.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy they shipped a POSIX `sh`, yes, but *not* at the `/bin/sh` location (until Solaris 11). So any scripts that had the standard maximally portable `#!/bin/sh -` hashbang would still need to deal with POSIX incompatibilities (on Solaris 10 and below). (Of course, you could somewhat reasonably take the position that you as the script writer shouldn't have to deal with that, and that it's an installer's/admin's responsibility to update the hashbang of your scripts on Solaris 10 and below.)

Answer (score 9):

Just pass your string to your function:

```
function my_function
{
    while test $# -gt 0
    do
        echo "do something with $1"
        shift
    done
}
my_string="cat
dog
bird"
my_function $my_string
```

gives you:

```
do something with cat
do something with dog
do something with bird
```

And if you really care about other whitespaces being taken as argument separators, first set your `IFS`:

```
IFS="
"
my_string="cat and kittens
dog
bird"
my_function $my_string
```

to get:

```
do something with cat and kittens
do something with dog
do something with bird
```

Do not forget to `unset IFS` after that.

Comment: +1 IFS splitting is also less prone to unexpected misbehaving than `read` without options, and strictly speaking more portable than `read -r`.

Answer (score 7):

if you use bash, setting IFS is all you need:

```
$ x="black cat
brown dog
yellow bird"
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ for word in $x; do echo "$word"; done
black cat
brown dog
yellow bird
```

Comment: Note that IFS is _not_ bash specific.

Comment: No, but the `$'\n'` construct is not available in every shell.

Comment: To avoid `$'\n'`, you can set IFS directly to the newline. I mean
    `IFS='<Press Enter here>'`

Answer (score 4):

Use `read` with a while loop:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line;
done
```

Comment: `$line` contains the string

Comment: No, line is the string, where the splitted string will appear. The correct answer would be: `while ... done <<< "$my_string"`

Comment: That would be bash-specific.

Answer (score 3):

Use `xargs`:

Depending on what you want to do with each line, it could be as simple as:

```
xargs -n1 func < file
```

or more complicated using:

```
cat file | xargs -n1 -I{} func {}
```

Comment: what is the `func` ?

Comment: @einverne, the function the OP wants each item passed to as an argument.

Comment: @ksb thanks for your response, i was thinking about `func` is a command.

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:

```
multrs="some multiple line string ...
...
..."

while read -r line; do
    echo $line;
done <<< "$mulstrs"
```

Variable $mulstrs must be **enclosed** in **double quotes**, otherwise spaces or carriage returns will interfere with the calculation.