# What does $'\n' mean in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

An answer in this stackoverflow question [In a Linux shell how can I process each line of a multiline string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051556/in-a-linux-shell-how-can-i-process-each-line-of-a-multiline-string) mentions that `$'\n'` is a special syntax "is not available in every shell".

I wonder what does the syntax mean?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the `QUOTING` section of the `bash` man page:

```
   Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word  expands  to
   string,  with  backslash-escaped  characters replaced as specified by the
   ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded  as
   follows:

...
              \n     new line
...

   The  expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been
   present.
```

This syntax is not part of the standard Unix Bourne shell.  It may be specific to bash, although I haven't looked around to see if other shells support it.

Comment: Perhaps also mention that this is definitely a Bashism.

Comment: @tripleee The `$'` strings actually aren't really a "bashism" per se: zsh supports it, busybox ash supports it, and I can't verify right now, but I think some ksh versions support it, and that syntax actually originated a long time ago: it just came a little too late to become properly standardized, but apparently a lot of shells support it.

Comment: @mtraceur; point taken; call it "non-portable" instead. I see the OP already edited his answer to clarify this (already in 2012!)

Comment: This is the [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) to the relevant section in the Bash manual.

Comment: I find it strange that `$'\0'` is not included in the decoding table..

Comment: @olejorgenb it *is* included in the decoding table. See the entry that reads: `\nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to three octal digits)`

Comment: Ah, missed the "one to". The reason I thought it wasn't included is that `cat /proc/4212/environ | tr $'\0' $'\n'` does not work :thinking-face. Using `"\0"` does works. But thinking about it - maybe it's not that easy to pass a `\0` to a command :D So some special handling like tr seems to do is needed.